# Launch two bash commands simultaneously and collect results from the process finished earlier

Tags: python, subprocess

Suppose I want to run two bash commands `c1` and `c2` from my Python scripts, which essentially process (but not modify) the same piece of data on Linux (hence this is no subtle race conditions).

Right now I would like to launch them simultaneously (with `os.system`), and see which one finishes quicker, once one process has finished, I will collect its output (could be dumpped into a file with `c1 >> log1.txt`), and terminate the other process.

Note that the processing time of two process could be largely different and hence observable, say one takes ten seconds, while the other takes 60 seconds.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Could we have a peak at your code :)

Comment: This sounds like you are having an ugly problem with your processing script and you are trying to fix it with an even more ugly workaround. Describe your real problem!

Comment: `os.system()` is the wrong tool. Use `subprocess.Popen()`, thus returning a separate Python object per process, and you can poll or wait for the processes separately (with timeouts, to allow checking both without putting your program in a busy-loop consuming a full CPU core). Beyond that, we'd need a [mcve] to make this concrete enough to be answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach that works without threading might look something like:

```
import os, subprocess, tempfile

def get_first_outfile(inputFileName):
    p1_stdout = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    p2_stdout = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['process-one', inputFileName], stdout=p1_stdout)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['process-two', inputFileName], stdout=p2_stdout)

    while True:
        if p1.poll() is not None:  # Process 1 finished first
            (file_keep, file_kill) = p1_stdout, p2_stdout
            (proc_keep, proc_kill) = p1, p2
            break
        if p2.poll() is not None:  # Process 2 finished first
            (file_keep, file_kill) = p2_stdout, p1_stdout
            (proc_keep, proc_kill) = p2, p1
            break
        time.sleep(0.1)           # Wait to poll again

    proc_kill.terminate()         # Terminate the process that didn't finish
    file_keep.seek(0)             # Rewind the output file we want to keep to the beginning
    file_kill.close()             # closing a tempfile deletes it

    if finished_first.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception("Process failed with status %r" % finished_first.returncode)
    return keep_outfile           # Return the output file we want to keep
```

---

Alternately, one can have Python call a shell and do the work there:

```
shellScript = '''
outOne=$(mktemp -t out.XXXXXX) || exit
outTwo=$(mktemp -t out.XXXXXX) || exit
processOne "$@" >"$outOne" & proc1_pid=$!
processTwo "$@" >"$outTwo" & proc2_pid=$!
wait -n # wait for one of the two processes to finish
if kill -0 "$proc1_pid"; then
  # proc1 is still running, so proc2 finished
  cat -- "$outTwo"
  kill "$proc1_pid"
else
  cat -- "$outOne"
  kill "$proc2_pid"
fi
'''

def get_output_from_first_process(inputFileName):
    return subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', shellScript, '_', inputFileName],
                                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that we *still* aren't using `os.system()`, and *also* aren't using `shell=True`: `wait -n` is a bash extension, so we need to ensure that bash -- not `/bin/sh` -- is available for it to function.